# Sharing files between ubuntu machines in home network

Tags: ubuntu, home-networking, file-sharing

I have two systems in my home wifi network running ubuntu. How can I share files in one so that it is accessible in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Ubuntu site at the bottom of the page- click on and type in 'file share' - this an answer to your question that I hope works for you.

- [Share between Ubuntu machines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16104/share-between-ubuntu-machines)
- [How to access the shared folder between two computers running ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9230/how-to-access-the-shared-folder-between-two-computers-running-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

join to  [dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) and use the free online space of 2 GB from everywhere with all your computers.

Comment: And of course there is [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/) with almost the same functionality